# How to set SA_ONSTACK flag

Tags: go, ibm-mq

My Go application connect to IBM MQ.

When my application throws segmentation violation error (signal SIGSEGV), signal handlers registered by IBM MQ make my application throw "non-Go code set up signal handler without SA_ONSTACK flag".

So how can I set that flag?

### My code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang/ibmmq"
)

type A struct {
    Str string
}

type B struct {
    Apointer *A
}

func main() {
    connectIBMMQ()

    b := B{}
    fmt.Println(b.Apointer.Str)
}

const (
    QMgrName       = `QMgrName`
    ChannelName    = `ChannelName`
    ConnectionName = `0.0.0.0(1416)`
    Username       = `username`
    Password       = `password`
)

func connectIBMMQ() {
    mqcd := ibmmq.NewMQCD()
    mqcd.ChannelName = ChannelName
    mqcd.ConnectionName = ConnectionName

    csp := ibmmq.NewMQCSP()
    csp.AuthenticationType = ibmmq.MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD
    csp.UserId = Username
    csp.Password = Password

    cno := ibmmq.NewMQCNO()
    cno.ClientConn = mqcd
    cno.Options = ibmmq.MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING + ibmmq.MQCNO_RECONNECT + ibmmq.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK
    cno.SecurityParms = csp

    ibmmq.Connx(QMgrName, cno)
}
```

### Ref

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q025880_.htm
https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#hdr-Go_programs_that_use_cgo_or_SWIG

### Full error

```
signal 11 received but handler not on signal stack
fatal error: non-Go code set up signal handler without SA_ONSTACK flag

runtime stack:
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.sigtramp called from 0x7f60f6e9a517
stack: frame={sp:0xc000046628, fp:0xc000046680} stack=[0xc00003e578,0xc000046978)
000000c000046528:  000000c000046530  00000000004549a0 <runtime.throw.func1+0> 
000000c000046538:  00000000004e2c3b  0000000000000039 
000000c000046548:  000000c000046568  00000000004415df <runtime.sigNotOnStack+127> 
000000c000046558:  00000000004e2c3b  0000000000000039 
000000c000046568:  000000c000046618  0000000000440c6d <runtime.sigtrampgo+749> 
000000c000046578:  000000000000000b  000000c000046600 
000000c000046588:  000000c000046880  0000000000000000 
000000c000046598:  0000000000000000  000000c000046628 
000000c0000465a8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465b8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465c8:  0000000000000000  000000c000000180 
000000c0000465d8:  0000000000000000  ffffffffffffffff 
000000c0000465e8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465f8:  0000000000000000  000000c000002000 
000000c000046608:  0000000000000000  0000000000008000 
000000c000046618:  000000c000046670  0000000000459a33 <runtime.sigtramp+67> 
000000c000046628: <000000000000000b  000000c0000469b0 
000000c000046638:  000000c000046880  000000c000046880 
000000c000046648:  000000c0000469b0  0000000000000000 
000000c000046658:  000000000000000b  000000c000046670 
000000c000046668:  00007f60f78213c0  000000000262e400 
000000c000046678: !00007f60f6e9a517 >000000c000046690 
000000c000046688:  8e26f8f48c919100  0000000000000000 
000000c000046698:  0000000000000000  0000000000000008 
000000c0000466a8:  0000000000000000  000000c000000180 
000000c0000466b8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466c8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466d8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466e8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466f8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046708:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046718:  0000000000000000  000000c000046f88 
000000c000046728:  0000000000000004  0000000000000012 
000000c000046738:  00000000004f21e1  0000000000000000 
000000c000046748:  00007f60f6e9b45a  0000000000000000 
000000c000046758:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046768:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046778:  0000000000000000 
runtime.throw(0x4e2c3b, 0x39)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x72
runtime.sigNotOnStack(0xb)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:576 +0x7f
runtime.sigtrampgo(0xb, 0xc0000469b0, 0xc000046880)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:334 +0x2ed
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.sigtramp called from 0x7f60f6e9a517
stack: frame={sp:0xc000046628, fp:0xc000046680} stack=[0xc00003e578,0xc000046978)
000000c000046528:  000000c000046530  00000000004549a0 <runtime.throw.func1+0> 
000000c000046538:  00000000004e2c3b  0000000000000039 
000000c000046548:  000000c000046568  00000000004415df <runtime.sigNotOnStack+127> 
000000c000046558:  00000000004e2c3b  0000000000000039 
000000c000046568:  000000c000046618  0000000000440c6d <runtime.sigtrampgo+749> 
000000c000046578:  000000000000000b  000000c000046600 
000000c000046588:  000000c000046880  0000000000000000 
000000c000046598:  0000000000000000  000000c000046628 
000000c0000465a8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465b8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465c8:  0000000000000000  000000c000000180 
000000c0000465d8:  0000000000000000  ffffffffffffffff 
000000c0000465e8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000465f8:  0000000000000000  000000c000002000 
000000c000046608:  0000000000000000  0000000000008000 
000000c000046618:  000000c000046670  0000000000459a33 <runtime.sigtramp+67> 
000000c000046628: <000000000000000b  000000c0000469b0 
000000c000046638:  000000c000046880  000000c000046880 
000000c000046648:  000000c0000469b0  0000000000000000 
000000c000046658:  000000000000000b  000000c000046670 
000000c000046668:  00007f60f78213c0  000000000262e400 
000000c000046678: !00007f60f6e9a517 >000000c000046690 
000000c000046688:  8e26f8f48c919100  0000000000000000 
000000c000046698:  0000000000000000  0000000000000008 
000000c0000466a8:  0000000000000000  000000c000000180 
000000c0000466b8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466c8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466d8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466e8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c0000466f8:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046708:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046718:  0000000000000000  000000c000046f88 
000000c000046728:  0000000000000004  0000000000000012 
000000c000046738:  00000000004f21e1  0000000000000000 
000000c000046748:  00007f60f6e9b45a  0000000000000000 
000000c000046758:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046768:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
000000c000046778:  0000000000000000 
runtime.sigtramp(0xc000046690, 0x8e26f8f48c919100, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8, 0x0, 0xc000000180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:357 +0x43

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 +0x1 fp=0xc00004afe8 sp=0xc00004afe0 pc=0x457e41

goroutine 1 [running]:
    goroutine running on other thread; stack unavailable
```

Comment: Could you provide your code for better understanding of what you are asking?

Comment: Hi @creyD,
My code is just simple: https://play.golang.org/p/Y-r7VuYdvIX

Comment: I have added one more ref from IBM MQ

Comment: Assuming the cgo code in question is part of whatever client library you're using for IBM MQ, that's where the issue is and that's what has to be fixed.

Comment: You are not actually showing any MQ code in your link, and that is most likely where you will have your coding error. There are go samples for MQ that you could use: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Go and https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang/tree/master/samples

Comment: Hi all, thank for your reply.

I have just updated my code and full error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the environment variable "MQS_NO_SYNC_SIGNAL_HANDLING=true" to disable some of MQ's signal setting. That should at least give a better idea of where the SEGV is coming from.